# 2nd PHP Include call fails

Tags: php

When I make a call to an include file a second time. My page crashes. Is there something in this include file that would prevent it from being called once in the header area and once in the footer area?

```
<div class="module context-nav">
<?php function findInclude () {
$directory = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$directory=substr($directory,9);
$directories = explode("/",$directory);
switch($directories[0]){
case 'students':
switch($directories[1]) {
case 'undergrad':
include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/students.php");
break;
case 'graduate':
include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/students.php");
break;
case 'society':
include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/students.php");
break;
case '4yearbsn':
include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/bsn.php");
break;
case 'postdegreebsn':
include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/postdegbsn.php");
break;
case 'postregbsn':
include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/postregbsn.php");
break;
case 'neps':
include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/neps.php");
break;
case 'master':
include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/masters.php");
break;
case 'postgradnp':
include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/postNP.php");
break;
case 'phd':
include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/phd.php");
break;
default:
include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/students.php");
break;
}
break;
case 'intranet':
    switch($directories[1]) {
case 'research':
include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/intranetresearch.php");
break;
case 'elearning':
include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/intranetelearning.php");
break;
default:
include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/intranet.php");
break;
}
break;


    case 'programs':
    switch($directories[1]) {
case 'neps':
include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/programs.php");
break;
case 'postreg':
include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/programs.php");
break;
case 'masters':
include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/programs.php");
break;
case 'practitioner':
include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/programs.php");
break;
case 'phd':
include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/programs.php");
break;
default:
include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/programs.php");
break;
}
break;
    case 'alumni':
      include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/alumni.php");
      break;
    case 'college':
    switch($directories[1]) 
{
case 'deansblog':
include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/college_deansblog.php");
break;
default:
include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/college.php");
break;
}
break;
    case 'research':
      include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/research.php");
   break;
    case 'cedn':
      include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/cne.php");
      break;
    case 'predeparture':
   switch($directories[1]) {
     case 'transcultural':
   include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/transcultural.php");
   break;



     default:
          include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/predeparture.php");
          break;
   }
   break;
    case 'custodycaring':
      include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/custodycaring.php");
      break;
   case 'predeparture':
      include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/internationalexperience.php");
      break;
    case 'aboriginal':
      include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/napm.php");
      break;
case 'rbcnursesforkids':
      include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/innovation.php");
      break;
    case 'casnie':
      include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/innovation.php");
      break;
 case 'elearning':
      include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/elearning.php");
      break;
 case 'virtuallab':
      include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/virtuallab.php");
      break;   
 case 'news':
      include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/college.php");
      break;
 case 'pandemic':
      include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/pandemic.php");
      break;
    case 'ihfc':
      include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/ihfc.php");
      break;
    case '75th':
      include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/75th.php");
      break;
case 'stylesheet':
      include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/stylesheet.php");
      break;   
    default:
        include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/blank.php");
break;
}
}
?>

<?php findInclude(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php

Comment: You can join a lot of cases.

Comment: if you included it twice you will get an error that findInclude() is already defined.

Answer (score 3):

Try using:

```
include_once();
```

See the PHP man, for more details.

Comment: won't include_once break it since I am calling this function twice?

Answer (score 1):

Always prefer an absolute path using include_once:

The differnce is **[include_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)** just checks if the script has been previously included or not.If it is then the second include will be ignored.

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nursing/includes/leftnavigation/students.php";
```

For strict checking,use **[require_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)** which does the same thing except the fact that it gives you a fatal error(halts execution of your script) rather than a warning.

Comment: won't include_once break it since I am calling this function twice?

Comment: so I can get it to not crash by having two functions and using include_once but the problem is that it still only loads the first include. When it gets to the second include for ....students.php it just returns nothing because it has already included that file.